# Occassional massive firewall log files on SuSE

Tags: linux, firewall, logging, suse

Occasionally, over a short period of seconds, my SuSE Enterprise 10 `/var/log/firewall` log file fills with identical entries except for the id. Here's an excerpt:

```
Jan 15 11:21:13 IKCSWeb kernel: SFW2-IN-ACC-RELATED IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:19:bb:2e:85:42:00:17:c5:d8:2e:2c:08:00 SRC=59.64.166.81 DST=207.194.99.122 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7810 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=24093 DPT=22 WINDOW=137 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jan 15 11:21:13 IKCSWeb kernel: SFW2-IN-ACC-RELATED IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:19:bb:2e:85:42:00:17:c5:d8:2e:2c:08:00 SRC=59.64.166.81 DST=207.194.99.122 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56845 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=24093 DPT=22 WINDOW=137 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jan 15 11:21:13 IKCSWeb kernel: SFW2-IN-ACC-RELATED IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:19:bb:2e:85:42:00:17:c5:d8:2e:2c:08:00 SRC=59.64.166.81 DST=207.194.99.122 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48949 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=24093 DPT=22 WINDOW=137 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

I'm a novice. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random internet people trying to ssh into your PC.  The DPT=22 which is the default ssh port.  SRC=59.64.166.81

https://www.db-ip.com/59.64.166.81

Checking whois the IP address belongs to china.
Random people scan the internet all the time in an attempt to see if they can login to other people's computer.  This is the recon phase, first phase, before attack.  I have recorded 10's of thousands of these, especially from china.

As long as you either:

1. Disable ssh
2. Strong ssh password and/or certificate
3. Up to date version of ssh

They won't be getting.

You are better off adding a rule to your firewall to block without logging.  I forgot the name of the Suse firewall tool, but it uses iptables on the back end.

This assumes eth0 is your internet connection.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

I recommend the firewall tool built-in to webmin tool.

Comment: That is great information. Thank you. An issue I have is that the disk isn't large enough to hold GB worth of these log entries daily. Can I filter out identical entries (identical other than the id)?

Comment: You are better off adding a rule to your firewall to block without logging.

Comment: @RickJolly You can also move `sshd` to nonstandard (i.e. `!=22`) port. Attackers usually scan most probable port(s).

Comment: @cybernard a rule to blacklist certain IPs, or whitelist our IPs?

Comment: White listing is definitely the way to go.  There are 4 billion IP addresses, and you may want to allow a few hundred in at most.  How many do you want to allow?

Comment: I only need to allow a handful, but some ips are dynamic so it'll be a pain to maintain.

Comment: Use whois to lookup their range and allow that.  For example 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255 is simply expressed at 192.168.0.1/24 and done.

Comment: @RickJolly  The problem is the SuSE GUI (user friendly and dumbed down) **yast firewall** only allows access to about 10% of the true functionally of iptables.  I forgot how primitive that tool is, and if you don't use it you have to setup another system, like cron, to save/load your firewall rules.  If you use the firewall tool built in to webmin you can at least, clumsy, access all the options.